# Aircrack-ng crashes my computer

Tags: aircrack-ng

So I am in the basics of pentesting and whenever I use the `aircrack-ng` command after a while my system reboots.

```
aircrack-ng -a 2 -b Mac_Address -w wordlist.txt /root/Desktop/*.cap
```

It runs for a couple of minutes and then crashes.
Is it a hardware problem, like not enough RAM, or is it something else? 
I have several wordlists, some are big ones (5 hours) and some are small (2 minutes). The fact is that this happens in the small wordlists.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry, I can't comment)

How big is you wordlist.txt? And how much RAM do you have?

This could be the problem. If not update your question with some more informations about your system and installed software

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. If you have a new question please [ask it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I just want to help him. Sorry that I can't comment yet. How should I ever get enough points if I am not allowed to answer

Comment: By asking thoughtful questions. OR answering questions that are sufficiently clear that clarifying comments are unnecessary. OR suggesting non-trivial constructive edits that fix issues with questions or answers. See [What is reputation? How do I earn, and lose, it?](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: You can also ask a question you have already solved, and then post an answer detailing the solution. You may get a better answer or we can learn from you. A win win for you and the AU community.